# run ionic framework with play! framework locally

Tags: playframework-2.0, ionic-framework

I've developed a little ionic app.
I've tested it using "ionic serve" and with Play framework running locally on my machine and everything works fine.

Now I would like to do the same thing while emulating my app with "ionic emulate iOS", but if I try this combination my app seems to be unable to reach my local server.

Is there something particular that I have to configure or do I have to put my server in production mode on my production server to work or it is even possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the intel xdk, here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools#download, it has a built in emulator that can simulate ios and android. Just import your project and click the emulate tab. Also has a built in text editor (brackets) a on device debugger, a test server for remotely testing on devices, and a build server for building the app.

Comment: yeah no problem. It is kinda crazy more people do not know about it. Great little tool